# Should we raise a close vote when reviewing first posts?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

It happens when I open the review page of the website, there is a question which is in both lists of *First Posts* and *Close Posts*. The problem here is that, if somebody first opens the *First Posts* review page, and he raise a vote to close to that specific question; when he continues his review to the *Close Posts* page and see the same question there, he will not have the option to agree with the raised flag for closing such question. The only option he will have is to retract his close vote which he raised in the previous review session.

When I faced such problem, I decided to first open the *Close Votes* review page. Because then I will not fail to review that question which is also on the *First Posts* page.

Also, the other strategy is that I do not vote to close a question even I find an off-topic question on the *First Posts* review page. I first, review such post for convenient grammar, title and tags, not being spam, etc; and when my review is complete, I go back to the question and vote it to be closed.

In these very rare moments, how do you decide on such question?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's OK to vote to close a question when you review it in "First Posts." So far as I can tell, it then gets removed from your "Close Votes" review queue, which is OK.

The thing that I think is important when voting to close while doing "First Posts" review is to welcome the person to the site and make sure to suggest how to improve their post.

Answer (score 0):

In the rare case, in which you cannot select the appropriate choice during a review because you already made this choice elsewhere, you should skip the review.

Note that this situation should only arise if engage multiple review queues simultaneously, e.g., if you go to the *Review* page and open all queues in new tabs. Going through the reviews one-by-one should avoid this.